# Remove empty lines from a file

Tags: substitute

I'm able to find empty lines with `/^$`, but when I go to remove them using `:%s/^$//`, nothing seems to happen. Yet, some form of substitution is being made, because the status line reads `XX substitutions on XX lines` where `XX` is the number of empty lines in the file.

Questions:

1. What substitutions are being made, as indicated by the status line?
2. How do I accomplish what I want to do (eliminate empty lines from a file)?

Comment: One answer to #2 is `:g/^$/d`

Comment: A solution would be to replace an actual character: `:%s/^\n//` but that depends on file format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `^` and `$` are *zero-width* items, so when you do `:%s/^$//` you’re substituting zero characters for zero characters
2. To actually perform the substitution, the idioms are

```
:g/^$/d
```

and

```
:g/^$/j
```